# Ajax call with Time interval zend framework

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework, request, nstimeinterval

What i want to do is basically to retrieve div and sub div content every 3 seconds. I am using ajax to send the data to the controller. but i am getting

```
$.ajax is not a function
http://localhost/index/editor
Line 25
```

This is the code i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setInterval(getAjax, 3000);

    function getAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'localhost/index',
            data: "some-data"     
        });
    }

</script>
```

1) I am i doing something wrong

2) how to receive data in zend controller

Comment: Have you included jQuery (or Zepto)?

Comment: Jquery is included in my default layout,and i disable it. does that effect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.ajax` is defined by jQuery. You have to include it before calling this function.

Answer (score 1):

Once jQuery is included in your page, you will be able to use the $.ajax() function.  After that, in your controller, you can access the data in the $_POST variable.  To make it easier, I usually use a JSON object to send data to the controller:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(getAjax, 3000);

        var data = {};
        data['field1'] = 'value1';
        data['field2'] = 'value2';
        function getAjax() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'localhost/index',
                data: data    
            });
        }

    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

And in your controller, you can use _getParam to find a value:

```
public function ajaxAction() {
    //Disable the view (if this is an AJAX call)
    if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }

    //Get posted data
    $field1 = $this->_getParam('field1');
    $field2 = $this->_getParam('field2');

    if($field1=='value1') {
        $jsonResp['isValid'] = 1;
        $jsonResp['gotValue'] = $field2;
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo Zend_Json::encode($json);
}
```

EDIT:
Oh, I forgot, you will probably want to check the response sent by your controller from your jQuery code.  You can achieve that in the following way

```
$.ajax({
//...
success: function(jsonResp) {
    if(jsonResp['isValid']) alert(jsonResp['gotValue']);
}
});
```